# Please give me an explanation of what this means (Basic)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just starting python, the book tells me I can create a this matrix diagonal if I use this following code, someone please explain what it means? The for i in, the Matrix[i][i] and why it's [0,1,2]
Thanks in advance.

```
Matrix = [[1,2,3,4],
          [5,6,7,8],
          [9,10,11,12]]
Diagonal = [Matrix[i][i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Which tutorial are you using to learn Python? We can probably point you at the appropriate section.

Comment: Whichever tutorial you are using probably has a breakdown of Python data structures and what they mean and how to use them etc. Understanding that, will help you understand this and why you get the following output: [1, 6, 11]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first assignment

```
Matrix = [[1,2,3,4],
      [5,6,7,8],
      [9,10,11,12]]
```

is setting the variable `Matrix` to a list of 3 elements, where each of those 3 elements is a list of 4 numbers. `Matrix[0]` holds the list `[1,2,3,4]`, `Matrix[1]` holds `[5,6,7,8]`, and `Matrix[2]` holds `[9,10,11,12]`.

The second assignment:

```
Diagonal = [Matrix[i][i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
```

is setting the variable `Diagonal` to a list of particular numbers inside `Matrix`. Each item in `Diagonal` is from a position in `Matrix` where the row index and the column index are the same (because `i` is being used for both indexes). `i` itself is running through the values 0, 1, 2, so `Diagonal` ends up with `[Matrix[0][0], Matrix[1][1], Matrix[2][2]`, which is `[1, 6, 11]`. `0` is the index of the first row and the first column, `1` is the index of the second row and the second column, `2` is the index of the third row and the third column.

Answer (score 0):

`[Matrix[i][i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]` is something called "list comprehension" it is awesome, and you should learn it ASAP. (it does something to every item in the list and then returns the results as a list)

overall it means `for i` - "i" is the variable we are using as a temporary holder.

`in [0,1,2]` - These are what "i" will be each time it iterates

`Matrix[i][i]` - each time access Matrix[i][i] and slap it into a list.

this list is assigned to `Diagonal`

without list comprehension it is equivalent to this:

```
Diagonal = []
for i in [0,1,2]:
     Diagonal.append(Matrix[i][i])
```

Comment: How is your `for loop` equivalent to the `list comp`? It would give a completely different result

Comment: brah, u kno i meant [i][i] :)

Answer (score -1):

`[0, 1, 2]` is used a as a list of indexes.

As Matrix is a multidimensional array you have rows and columns so:

You get  `row 0 column 0` on the first iteration `-> [1,2,3,4] = 1`

You get  `row 1 column 1` on the second iteration `-> [5,6,7,8] = 6`

You get  `row 2 column 2` on the third iteration `-> [9,10,11,12] = 1`